# How to set autofocus on Vue froala component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, froala

I have a vue froala component

```
         <froala
            v-model="note"
            :tag="'textarea'"
            :config="config"
          >
          </froala>
```

In script , i set focus to true to set autofocus on text area. But its not working

```
config: {
      focus: true
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
config: {
      autofocus: true
  }
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<froala
            v-model="note"
            :tag="'textarea'"
            :config="config"
            ref="froalaFocus"
          >
          </froala>
    ...
    this.$refs.froalaFocus.focus()
```

you may need to use the `$el`like so: `this.$refs.froalaFocus.$el.focus()` possibly dig a bit deeper (your ref could be an array in which case you need tofind the element you want to focus on.

Comment: it shows TypeError: this.$refs.froalaEditor.$el.focus() is not a function.
When print the this.$refs.froalaEditor.$el, it shows
<textarea data-v-54d23b60="" autofocus="autofocus" style="display: none;"></textarea>

Comment: that means that you havent got the element, console to see what you have and then grab it.